# Getting IgniteCheckedException: Default Ignite instance has already been started exception when enabling Persistence on single Node

Tags: java, spring, ignite, high-availability

I am deploying an application where I need to maintain some data in Ignite cache. I used in memory Ignite cache. Here is the Ignite configuration I have used:

```
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="IGNITE_DATA" />
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC" />
                <property name="writeSync"
                    value="PRIMARY_SYNC" />
                <property name="backups"
                    value="${IGNITE_CACHE_BACKUPS}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Now when I deployed multiple instances of my application and stored data in Ignite cache. Its shared among all the application instances.
Even if any any instance goes down and comes up after sometime it has the latest data via Ignite cache sync.

But issue occurs when all the application instances go down. When they come up data is gone since it was not persisted. For persistence I used **dataStorageConfiguration** property and enabled the persistence. Here is the change I added to Ignite configuration:

```
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
        <bean
            class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                <bean
                    class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                    <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />

                </bean>
            </property>

            <!-- Changing Write Ahead Log Mode. -->
            <property name="storagePath" value="${IGNITE_BC_STORE_PATH}"/>
            <property name="walMode" value="LOG_ONLY" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Now when I deploy my application and I try and start Ignite from Java code as mentioned below:

```
log.info("Initializing IGNITE...");
ignite = Ignition.start(getClass().getResource(CONF_FILE));
```

I get an exception every time stating the default instance has already started.Tried several things but didn't work. Even if I remove the CacheConfiguration from Ignite Configuration and just keep dataStorageConfiguration I still getting the same error. Error is :

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Default Ignite instance has already been started.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1076)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:962)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:881)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:373)
```

Normally this error comes when we try and run multiple Ignite nodes under same JVM but here I am running single node per JVM. Then also getting the error.
Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, you have more than one `IgniteConfiguration` bean in your config file. If one configuration bean extends another one, then make sure, that the parent is abstract.

Comment: I've checked the configuration file... It only contains 1 Ignite configuration bean. If i remove the dataStorageConfiguration property for persistence. The error goes away.. there is some issue with this property

Comment: Could you specify the whole configuration file, that doesn't let the node start? I'd like to check in on my side.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. Seems like the issue was not woth the Ignite configuration but was with Spring Framework configuration.

I was creating the bean for the Ignite class using the lazy-init=true. I switched that to the eager-init and that resolved my issue.
Not sure how exactly it solved this but it worked at least in my case.

Comment: Can't create Ignite twice in the same spring app? Strange...